# dojo -Dojox grid cell select gets enabled on column or window resize

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have enhanced grid with enhanced gird and one of the column has drop down.
The requirement is upon clicking on checkbox i want row to get disabled along with select box.
But the problem is upon window or column resize the select box gets enabled.
Here is the code.

```
<html>
    <div id="gridDiv"></div>
</html>
    <script>
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid");
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
    dojo.require("dojox.grid.enhanced.plugins.IndirectSelection");

    dojo.ready(function () {
    var data = {
        identifier: 'id',
        items: []
    };
    var data_list = [{
        col2: false,
        col3: 'But are not followed by two hexadecimal'
    }, {
        col2: false,
        col3: 'Because a % sign always indicates'
    }, {
        col2: false,
        col3: 'Signs can be selectively'
    }];
    var rows = 4;
    for (var i = 0, l = data_list.length; i < rows; i++) {
        data.items.push(dojo.mixin({
            id: i + 1
        }, data_list[i % l]));
    }
    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
        data: data
    });

    /*set up layout*/
    var layout = [{
        cells: [{
            'name': 'Column 1',
                'field': 'id',
                'width': '100px'
        }, {
            'name': 'Column 2',
                'field': 'col2',
                'width': '100px'
        }, {
            'name': 'Column 3',
                'field': 'col3',
                'width': '200px'
        }, {
            'name': 'Column 4',
                'field': 'col4',
                'width': '150px',
            alwaysEditing: true,
            editable: true,
            type: 'dojox.grid.cells.Select',
            options: ['new', 'read', 'replied']
        }]
    }];

    /*create a new grid:*/
    var grid = new dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid({
        id: 'grid',
        store: store,
        structure: layout,
        plugins: {
            indirectSelection: {
                headerSelector: false,
                width: "10px",
                styles: "text-align: center;"
            }
        }
    },
    document.createElement('div'));

    /*append the new grid to the div*/
    dojo.byId("gridDiv").appendChild(grid.domNode);

    /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
    grid.startup();
    dojo.connect(dijit.byId('grid'), 'onSelected',

    function (rowIndex) {
        dijit.byId('grid').rowSelectCell.setDisabled(rowIndex, true);
        dijit.byId('grid').getCell(4).getEditNode(rowIndex).setAttribute('disabled', true);

    });

});
</script>
```

Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ZgH8z/1/

Please note I am not supposed to disable column resizing,since columns can increase according to requirement.

Comment: I cannot get the checkbox to become enabled by resizing the window or column, nor do I see the row become disabled in your JSFiddle.

Comment: when you click on checkbox the select box gets disabled,after that just resize any column the select box gets enabled .

Comment: I stand corrected - I see it now.